# Apache2 Make a subdomain access a local FTP server

Tags: apache-http-server, php

Is there any way to connect a Apache2 subdomain by using `httpd-vhosts.conf` and:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
 ServerName sub.domain.com
 DocumentRoot "C:/bla/subfolder"
</VirtualHost>
```

To a FTP server running on `10.0.0.4:21` and to serve it's contents as if it was a real folder?
And if not, what could I do?

Answer (score 0):

No. Apache is an http server, not an FTP server, so this is not possible.

You can install an FTP server and associate a login + password to provide a home directory which matches the document root. Provided you mind permissions this is pretty standard. Exactly how you would do this would depend on your OS and FTP server.